# How do I export my state from my stack while using Spacelift?

Tags: terraform, spacelift

I am currently using Spacelift and on my stack, the state is managed by Spacelift.

I am happy with this but I want to export the state to an Amazon S3 bucket, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Terraform state file can be pulled and then exported using a [Task](https://docs.spacelift.io/concepts/run/task#performing-a-task).

For example, to export the state to an Amazon S3 bucket, you would run the following command as a Task:

terraform state pull > state.json && aws s3 cp state.json s3://

For that example to work, the stack needs to have write access to the AWS S3 bucket, possibly via an [AWS Integration](https://docs.spacelift.io/integrations/cloud-providers/aws).

You could also set up a [hook](https://docs.spacelift.io/concepts/stack/stack-settings#customizing-workflow) to constantly run this command at a specific part of your run.